# Equivalent of NumPy index arrays with standard Python lists or arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, matrix-indexing

I can use an array or a list to index into `numpy.array`, e.g.:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
print(a[[1, 3]])
```

will produce

```
[2 4]
```

Is there an equivalent construct to index into a standard Python list or array?

Just to be more specific: indexing has to be with an array and indexing pattern is random, i.e. not possible with slicing. Here is a better example:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
i = [3, 0, 1]
print(a[i])
.....
[4 1 2]
```

Comment: I don't think so, that is the reason why we use NumPy.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by equivalent. `[my_list[i] for i in index_list]` would give such result.

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: In this specific case a slice would do. But you are probably not just looking for evenly spaced indices, do you?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi No. I'm looking for a general case.

Comment: @bb1 This is a good option in a pinch.

Comment: If you try indexing with a list, you get a clear statement of what is possible, `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import itemgetter 

print(itemgetter(1,3)(a))
```

and to turn it into a list:

```
print(list(itemgetter(1,3)(a)))
```

Comment: Which is implemented as an iteration on the indices: `tuple(obj[i] for i in items)`

Comment: Not quite there, since it indexes with and produces a tuple not an array.